# makefile how to output to separate build directory

Tags: makefile

I have this directory structure:

```
makefile
src
    foo.c
build
```

My goal is simply to build foo.c and output the build files to the build directory.

I have the following makefile:

```
SRCS_DIR := ./src
BUILD_DIR := ./build

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRCS_DIR) -name "*.c")
OBJS := $(subst $(SRCS_DIR),$(BUILD_DIR),$(SRCS))
OBJS := $(OBJS:.c=.o)

test.exe: $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

The problem is the pattern rule. One of the object files is `build/foo.o`. The problem is that `%.c` gets turned into `build/foo.c`, which doesn't exist. What I want `%.c` to be is `src/foo.c` instead, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stem of the pattern must match exactly.  So if you want a pattern that will put things into a different directory, you have to modify the pattern so that the non-matching parts are not part of the stem.  So you can write:

```
build/%.o : src/%.o
        gcc -c $< -o $@
```

so that the `%` matches only the common string.